# Parallel Relay light switch

Tags: switch

An existing light switch is to be augmented with a parallel [Sensor Switch PP20 relay](https://www.acuitybrands.com/products/detail/88272/sensor-switch/pp20/power-pack-with-20-amp-relay), which is driven by PIR (passive infrared) sensors.

The current switch is a two terminal device and was wired into the hot side of the lighting circuit:
[image]

The upper black leg is hot and connected to the lower black leg upon command.   The wiring of the relay's terminals is well-understood.  The two bare wires must be connected to the upper (hot) leg:

[image]

Is there a clever method / part that would allow the two bare wires to be connected to the black wire without removing the black leg from the timer switch?

Wiring is not easily taken out of the switch: Side view of incumbent timer-switch:

[image]

UPDATE:

The faceplate of the timer switch was removed and revealed two screws to clamp down the existing wiring connections.  Screws were loosened: stranded relay wiring was inserted follow by solid core wiring:

[image]

Comment: Seems odd that you can't disconnect the wire...  connecting the wires together and running a pigtail to the switch would be the normal way to handle this.

Comment: What make and model is the relay you are using?

Comment: OP update to reflect a SensorSwitch PP20 relay.

Comment: I kind of get the impression this is an old school smart switch, and it has a "safety cover" on the back that pops off to gain access to the wires.

Comment: i would chop it at the midpoint and shove them all into a wago terminal.

Comment: Yeah, I coulda' told you that.  I installed one of those last year and that's how they work. Woulda worked better if you had shown or mentioned up front what kind of thing it was, instead of showing us a generic black hunk of plastic...

Comment: @Harper Thanks for the feedback.  Will try to post better photos next time